# Grabbing a single cell from a .csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, math, cell

I currently have a project in which I am trying to learn as I go, and I can't seem to figure out how to create a variable from a .csv that is created from the code I've already done. The code I have so far is the following:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source_code = requests.get('http://eoddata.com/stockquote/NASDAQ/AAPL.htm').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "lxml")

table = soup.find_all('table')[7]

df = (pd.read_html(str(table)))[0]
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]

df.to_csv('file2.csv', sep=';',index=False)
df_data = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', sep=';')
print(df_data)

test = df.iloc[[0],[4]]
tester = df.iloc[[1],[4]]
print(test)
print(tester)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
       Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  Open Interest
0  02/06/18  154.8  163.7  154.0  163.0  68104100              0
1  02/05/18  159.1  163.9  156.0  156.5  72738500              0
2  02/02/18  166.0  166.8  160.1  160.5  86593800              0
3  02/01/18  167.2  168.6  166.8  167.8  47230700              0
4  01/31/18  166.9  168.4  166.5  167.4  32478900              0
5  01/30/18  165.5  167.4  164.7  167.0  46048100              0
6  01/29/18  170.2  170.2  167.1  168.0  50640400              0
7  01/26/18  172.0  172.0  170.1  171.5  39143000              0
8  01/25/18  174.5  175.0  170.5  171.1  41529000              0
9  01/24/18  177.3  177.3  173.2  174.2  51105000              0
0  Close
1  163.0
0  Close
2  156.5
```

When I try to do math with my obtained numbers 163.0 and 156.5 I do the following:

```
print(tester - test)
```

But I get the output of:

```
1   NaN
2   NaN
```

What am I doing incorrectly? What would be the correct way of assigning the selected number as an integer or variable to be used in math formulas? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tester` and `test` are both pandas Series.  When you subtract one Series from another, the operation gets aligned on the index.  In this case, one Series has in index of [1] and the other has an index of [2], so there's no alignment.

One of several ways to get around this would be to access the underlying NumPy arrays on top of which the Series are built.  These are agnostic to the labelling of the index.

```
import numpy

print(np.asscalar(tester.values - test.values))
```

However, the more direct way would be to specify each as a scalar at start.  you can do:

```
test = df.iat[0, 4]
tester = df.iat[1, 4]
```

to get access to single scalar values.  Then you can run `print(tester - test)` as you do now.

Comment: When I change to df.iat, and attempt the math calculation it outputs TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' . What would be the solution? Or any guidance as to what I need to be looking for.

Comment: Just figured it out that they were still considered to be 'str' or strings. I have converted them to floats using test = float(df.iat[0, 4]) and it is now calculating correctly. Thank you for the help!